# Android: How to make soft keyboard not appear at all

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have several EditText views in my activity and I do not want to have the soft keyboard appearing all the time, when a click inside an EdiText. I work with an AVD running android 2.1 and I have tested the following without success.

Inside the onCreate():

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or

```
 CrazyACT.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(crazyEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or within the manifest file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `"stateAlwaysHidden"`

Comment: thanx but it didn't help either... it's like I'm missing something way too basic....btw, the edittext views have inputtype: default... any ideas?

Comment: still not what i'm looking for :(

Comment: Use `setOnFocusChangedListener()` and if the view is focused do this

 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(crazyEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);


Or redirect the focus to another view.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```